# как из многомерного массива сделать одномерный

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, не могу придумать алгоритм как из многомерного массива сделать одномерный.
Имеется такой двумерный массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
            (
                    [entry_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [title] => [QUOTE]123vbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbt[/QUOTE]
                    [post_date] => 1459870957
                    [reply_count] => 0
                    [view_count] => 59

            )
    [1] => Array
            (
                    [entry_id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [title] => ddddd
                    [post_date] => 1459882684
                    [reply_count] => 0
                    [view_count] => 18

            )
```

На выходе сформировать такой одномерный массив:

```
Array
(
    [entry_id] => 1
    [user_id] => 1
    [title] => [QUOTE]123vbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbt[/QUOTE]
    [post_date] => 1459870957
    [reply_count] => 0
    [view_count] => 59

)
Array
(
    [entry_id] => 2
    [user_id] => 1
    [title] => ddddd
    [post_date] => 1459882684
    [reply_count] => 0
    [view_count] => 18

)
```

Comment: У вас на выходе два одномерных массива, судя по примеру. Вы это имели в виду?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Comment: а чем не устраивает обращаться к этим массивам `$arrray[0]` ? чем лучше куча переменных $array0,...

Comment: Дело в том что массив нужно рендерить во вьюшку,
а во вьюшке не предусмотрен парсинг двумерного массива

Comment: отдавайте во "вьюшку" $arrray[0], $arrray[1]... это обычный foreach сделает

Comment: @kok's неужели нет шаблонизатора, который работает с foreach во вью? Это довольно странно

Comment: К сожалению нет.Только одномерный массив может парсить.

Comment: @kok's то есть если у вас будет большоооой многомерный массив с несколькими вложеностями вы будете генерить несколько десятков переменных? Это очень ......ооочень неправильно.... Я бы вам посоветовал лучше для начала найти что-то, что сможет работать со всеми видами данных во вью.....прикрутить какой-либо шаблонизатор, допилить систему самому и т.д, нежели заниматься таким изуверством........ а по теме splash58 уже написал... передавайте во вью $arrray[0], $arrray[1]  - это и есть два одномерных массива